# divisibility problem of unknown positive integer

Tags: elementary-number-theory, contest-math

If $a,b \in \mathbb{Z}^+$ such that $b^2+ab+1|a^2+ab+1$, prove that $a=b$.

I don't have any clue on solving this problem, can anyone give me some hints? I know $a \geq b$ and $b^2+ab+1|a^2-b^2$.

Also, can we generalize the problem? It seems that the problem is a very special case. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If positive integer $d|(a^2+ab+1)$ and $d|(b^2+ab+1)$

$d$ will divide $\{a(b^2+ab+1)-b(a^2+ab+1)\}=a-b$

$\implies b^2+ab+1$ must divide $a-b$

But as $b\ge1, b^2+ab+1\ge 1+a+1=a+2>a-1\ge a-b$

So, $b^2+ab+1$ can only divide $a-b$ if the later is $=0$